# Auth laravel parse

Tags: mongodb, laravel, parsing, laravel-5

I have problem with login laravel parse. I use auth for connection and I use this library for to do parsehttps://github.com/sirthxalot/laravel-parse and the doc for tutorial https://laravel-parse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/object-model.html

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
                echo "OK";
            }else{
                echo "Bad post";
            }
```

After the post data, my result is "bad post"

please help me

Comment: show your `route` and `view` codes. :)

Comment: @Capt.Teemo This is my route code `Route::post('/doLogin', 'Auth\LoginController@doLogin');` and view code `<form action="/doLogin" method="POST" id="loginForm"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" required><button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme login-btn">Connexion</button></form>`